# Loop through UITextField's and store double values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm having trouble looping through a set of dynamically created UITextFields and storing those values as a double to be added to an array later on. I'm still pretty new to obj-c programming so bear with me if this question seems trivial. Thanks. This is what I have so far.

```
NSMutableArray *textFieldCashArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
double textFieldCash;
for (int y=0; y<25; y++) {       
    UITextField *myLabel = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:y];            
    textFieldCash =  [myLabel.text doubleValue];
    [textFieldCashArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:textFieldCash]];    
}
```

P.S and here is the error message I'm getting

```
Pro[962:b303] -[UIControl text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x680f850
2012-04-01 16:05:46.305 iFinance Pro[962:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught      exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIControl text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x680f850'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Comment: Where exactly is this code in your ViewController?

Comment: Are these `UITextField`'s in a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that the loop variable is being used as the tag, and the loop starts at zero.  viewWithTag will answer either the receiver or one of it's subviews with a given tag, so if the view controller's main view has tag==0 (which it probably does), your first text request is being sent to that top-level view.

Try setting the text field tags to some non-zero value, starting at SOME_OFFSET.  Then in your loop:

```
for (y=0; y<25; y++) {
     UITextField *myLabel = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:y+SOME_OFFSET]; 
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

danh is most certainly right about the cause and solution to this problem. Just to add a little, cases like this can be somewhat avoided by checking the Class before casting.

```
if ([[self.view viewWithTag:y] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    UITextField *myLabel = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:y];            
    textFieldCash =  [myLabel.text doubleValue];
    [textFieldCashArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:textFieldCash]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create array at first:

```
NSMutableArray *textFieldCashArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

**Edit**
Your error log shows that you are receiving some another UIControl object (UIBtton for example) instead of UITextField. Check your tags on xib (or algorith if you set programmatically) and be sure that UITextField objects has corresponding tags